# Getting claims with azure ad using wsfedration and Owin middleware

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, owin, ws-federation

I'm trying to add authentication option to support Azure AD in an asp.net application. The web.config file has some options:

```
<add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
  <add key="ida:Realm" value="..." />
  <add key="ida:LogoutReply" value="..." />
  <add key="ida:OwinWsFederationEnabled" value="true" />
```

In addition, the authentication is configured in code like this:

```
public partial class Startup{
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app){
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {                
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString(...),
            LogoutPath = new PathString(...),                
        });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        });


        var authenticationOptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            MetadataAddress = metadata,
            Wtrealm = realm,
            Wreply = reply,
            Caption = caption,
            SignOutWreply = logoutreply,
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {                        
                ValidateIssuer = false
            }
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        };

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(authenticationOptions);   
    }               
}
```

This kind of works, because it redirects me to azure login and back to the app login path. But there, when all is supposed to be ok, I'm not getting any information about the newly logged in user.

```
var oid = GetClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");
```

with this or any other claim type, for that matter. All the claims are returning null-values.

The app is registered to my Azure AD directory as multitenant.
If I set the metadatalocation to be the tenant specific metadata, the AAD won't redirect me back to the application as the azure ad user is from another tenant.

What am I missing here to get the user claims from Azure AD?

Comment: Can you not use OAuth 2.0 with Open ID Connect?

Comment: Yeah, I would also recommend to move away from WS-Fed in favour of OpenID Connect.